One pipeline for several repositories, different templates for different projects
Environment: Azure DevOps Server 2022.0 with Windows-agents
We have several big Windows projects in different Git-repos. They should be built by a single YAML-pipeline, using project-specific templates. I created a YAML repo for anything pipeline.
I would like the triggering repo to set a variable that I can use further down the line as part of a template name, and in the build id. Not only that, I would like to be able to specify, for a manual run, which project to use, and use that information in the same way.
Azure-pipelines.yml:
resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: AAA
      type: git
      name: AAA
      ref: main
      trigger:
        branches:
          include:
            - main

    - repository: BBB
      type: git
      name: BBB
      ref: main
      trigger:
        branches:
          include:
            - main

    - repository: YAML
      type: git
      name: YAML-Automation
      ref: main
      trigger:
        - none

parameters:
- name: projectToBuild
  displayName: "Project to build:"
  type: string
  default: AAA
  values:
  - AAA
  - BBB
  - CCC

variables:
  productName: $(Build.Repository.Name)
  productVersion: 5.0.1

name: $(Build.Repository.Name)_$(productVersion)_$(Date:yyMMdd)$(Rev:rr)

I guess because a trigger from a repo happens after the YAML code has been compiled, the information is not available when "name" is set. But when I output the variable, it shows the correct information:
When repo BBB triggers,
echo Build.Repository.Name =  $(Build.Repository.Name) 

shows BBB, but the build has the name
#YAML-Automation_5.0.1_24070505
The checkout should be only for the YAML-repo and for the triggering one, so I need the name of the triggering repo again, which is empty.
Further down the line, I would like to use, for example, a template jobStuff-$(productname).yml, but productName is empty, and it doesn't work.
Finally, for a manual run, I would like to use the value of the manual project selection, projectToBuild, as input for productName, guess that would just require an "if manual", as in $[eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'Manual')].
Should my general approach work?
What could I do to get the name of the triggering into a usable variable?

As per Predefined variables, you have some limitations when using variable $(Build.Repository.Name):

It cannot be used in template expressions such as jobStuff${{ variables['Build.Repository.Name'] }}.yaml
It cannot be part of the build number or as a version control tag

In order to solve these limitations and even reduce a part of the pipeline's complexity I suggest to use a separate pipeline for each product.
Example
Create a base pipeline with all the resources, variables etc used by all products and uses the product job template:
# base-pipeline.yaml

parameters:
  - name: productName
    displayName: Name of the product to build
    type: string

  # Product version can either be set as a common variable for all pipelines/products 
  #, or, as an alternative, as a parameter in each pipeline (in case each product has a different version)
  - name: productVersion
    displayName: Version of the product to build
    type: string
    default: $(productVersion)

# Add resources that are used by all products/pipelines here
resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: YAML
      type: git
      name: YAML-Automation
      ref: main
      trigger:
        - none

variables:
  # Common variables that are used by all products/pipelines, such as productVersion etc
  - template: /pipelines/variables/common-variables.yaml

  # optionally include a product specific variables template
  # - template: /pipelines/variables/${{ parameters.productName }}-variables.yaml

jobs:
  - template: /pipelines/jobs/jobStuff-${{ parameters.productName }}.yml
    parameters:
      productVersion: ${{ parameters.productVersion }}
      # other parameters here

For each product (e.g. foo) create a dedicated pipeline that extends from base-pipeline.yaml:
# foo-pipeline.yaml

# Product version can either be set as a common variable for all pipelines/products 
#, or, as an alternative, as a parameter in each pipeline (in case each product has a different version)
# parameters:
#   - name: productVersion
#     displayName: Version of the product to build
#     type: string
#     default: 5.0.1

# This is a dedicated pipeline for 'foo' product, so name can be hard-coded
name: foo_$(productVersion)_$(Date:yyMMdd)$(Rev:rr)

# optionally use a parameter for product version
# name: foo_${{ parameters.productVersion }}_$(Date:yyMMdd)$(Rev:rr)

# Add product/pipeline specific resources here
resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: foo
      type: git
      name: foo
      ref: main
      trigger:
        branches:
          include:
            - main

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

extends:
  template: /pipelines/base-pipeline.yaml
  parameters:
    productName: foo # <--------------- Product name is hard-coded
    # productVersion: ${{ parameters.productVersion }}

Notes:

Creating a dedicated pipeline for each product might seem a lot of extra work, but by extending from a base pipeline you can remove some duplication and even some complexity, as you don't have to use stages or jobs conditions or if/else clauses to decide which product to run.
productVersion can be set independently for each product (or, as alternative, you can for example use a global variable if all products should use the same version)
Regarding manual runs, just queue the correspondent product pipeline (e.g. foo-pipeline.yaml)


Thanks you very much! That's a great solution, and really solves my problem! I found that "repositories" cannot be used in both the foo- and the base-pipeline (see here, so I moved them to foo, and everything seems to be working perfectly.

@HaraldJ glad to help. On the one hand there are more pipelines and files, but on the other hand code is easier to maintain :-)

@HaraldJ PS: consider upvoting and/or accepting my answer. Thanks!

don't know if it's related: Using YAML in a separate Git repository, with the excellent "extend" solution you suggested, suddenly makes DevOps use a different working directory for every job: The first job uses _work/1, the second _work/2, etc. This didn't happen before, and, as all the builds are on directory _work/1, anything other than the first job fails. And I'm quite lost, hoping you might have an idea, or know where my mistake is!

@HaraldJ impossible to know what's going on without seeing some code. Are you using hard-coded paths or predefined variables? Please create a new question for that, and don't forget to include all the relevant YAML code and details.

You need to manage the variables and ensure that the information about the triggering repository is available when needed.
Here is an example of how to structure your azure-pipelines.yml:
resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: AAA
      type: git
      name: AAA
      ref: main
      trigger:
        branches:
          include:
            - main

    - repository: BBB
      type: git
      name: BBB
      ref: main
      trigger:
        branches:
          include:
            - main

    - repository: YAML
      type: git
      name: YAML-Automation
      ref: main
      trigger: none

parameters:
- name: projectToBuild
  displayName: "Project to build:"
  type: string
  default: ''
  values:
  - AAA
  - BBB
  - CCC

variables:
  productName: ${{ coalesce(parameters.projectToBuild, variables['Build.Repository.Name']) }}
  productVersion: 5.0.1

name: $(productName)_$(productVersion)_$(Date:yyMMdd)$(Rev:rr)

stages:
- stage: Build
  jobs:
    - job: BuildJob
      displayName: Build $(productName)
      steps:
        - checkout: self

        - ${{ if eq(variables['productName'], 'AAA') }}:
          - template: jobStuff-AAA.yml

        - ${{ if eq(variables['productName'], 'BBB') }}:
          - template: jobStuff-BBB.yml

        - ${{ if eq(variables['productName'], 'CCC') }}:
          - template: jobStuff-CCC.yml

        - script: |
            echo "Build.Repository.Name: $(Build.Repository.Name)"
            echo "Product Name: $(productName)"


As per the predefined variables, variable $(Build.Repository.Name) is NOT available in templates so setting the variable productName and using it in template expressions such as ${{ if ... }} will probably not work as expected.

Great,  that seems to be working well, thank you! I didn' think of coalesce, clever!
It does NOT seem to work within called templates though. I tried passing on productName as a parameter, it didn't make any difference.
As I have product-dependent templates in several levels of templates, it would be great if you could think of a solution as well.

@HaraldJ one more thing -  variable $(Build.Repository.Name) cannot be used as part of the build number. See Predefined variables.
